# MVC4 EF 5 Debugging in VS 2010 against remote database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

When I try to debug my MVC4/EF 5 app locally in VS2010, against a remote database, the following happens.

Source of error (InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs):

```
using (var context = new UsersContext())
{
    if (!context.Database.Exists()) // <-- Exception here!
    {
        // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
```

Stack trace (only the first line):

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'mydb'.]
```

After debugging i find out that the following connectionstring is used:

```
"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=mydb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=mydb;Password=mydb;Application Name=EntityFrameworkMUE"
```

This is the real connectionstring in Web.Config:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=hostname.com;Initial Catalog=mydb;User ID=mydb;Password=mydb;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Code snippet from AccountModels.cs:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

Its quite apparent that DefaultConnection should be used, but along the way its modified...

When I publish my site to the remote server, where the sql server is also hosted, everything works just fine.

Solutions mentioned in other posts have not worked for me, such as naming the connection in Web.Config to the name of my DbContext class.

**Edit - I've done some more experimenting...**

This does not work:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext() : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

But this does:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("Data Source=hostname.com;Initial Catalog=mydb;User ID=mydb;Password=mydb;MultipleActiveResultSets=True")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

I get the feeling my Web.Config isnt used/recognized when debugging locally.

Help is still needed :-P

Comment: For now i've installed IIS 7.5 locally, and attach to that process for debugging. The correct connectionstrings are used. I am still interested in a solution since this method involves extra work for each site i want to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this recent and it had something to do with Name=EntityFrameworkMUE, our resolution was to specify the connection string in the app settings file and then reference the base through ConfigurationManager.

```
base(new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString), true) {}
```

Comment: This did not work. It did however work when i used the connection string itself as argument to public UsersContext() : base.

It continues to run but now fails at WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

It seems like it fails everywhere i want to pass the connectionstring name as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely doing a XSLT transform on your web.config during publishing.  You should check to see if you have web.release.config file (or web.debug.config) and change the defaultconnection connection string in your local web.config file to match.

Comment: Nothing is published. I am debugging in VS 2010. I believe VS 2010 built in development server is used :)

Comment: Do a solution wide search for `localhost`.  Perhaps you have some code running in global.asax that is overriding it at run time?

Comment: I searched the solution and found nothing weird. Just configuring log4net and setting my own ViewEngine in Global.asax.cs

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps my answer will be strange but I came across this situation, and I solved it when change my connectionstring as follow.

from

```
DefaultConnection
```

to

```
UsersContext
```

I changed connectionstring to DbContext class name.

Comment: Already tried that as i mentioned in my post. Thanks though :)